# Error 'list' object has no attribute 'split' cuando intento separar dos elementos de texto (números) extraídos de una web parseada

Tags: python, split, web-scrapping

Primero de todo me presento... me llamo Alfred y no soy programador. Lo que pasa es que necesito crear una serie de CSVs para poder extraer unos resultados de deportes que luego aplico a un programa de animación.
Y para extraer los datos de una web estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://www.fcf.cat/resultats/2324/futbol-11/tercera-federacion/grup-v'
html=requests.get(url).content
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
genres = [a.text.strip() for a in soup.select("td[class='p-5 resultats-w-equip tr'] > a")]
genras = [a.text.strip() for a in soup.select("td[class='p-5 resultats-w-equip tl'] > a")]
dates=[d.get_text() for d in soup.find_all("div", class_="tc fs-17 white bg-darkgrey p-r")]
data = {'LOCAL': genres[:8], 'GOLES':dates.split("-")[0], 'VISITANTE': genras[:8],'GOLES':dates.split("-")[1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

El problema és que cuando se ejecuta el código se produce el siguiente error en la línea 11. Dándome el siguiente mensaje: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
La idea inicial és que, una vez obtenido el texto de la etiqueta la pueda dividir en dos y crear así una tabla con equipo local, goles, equipo visitante y goles.
Si alguien me puede ayudar.
Muchísimas grácias y perdón si no me he explicado bien o algo!!!

Comment: Aquí `dates.split("-")[0]` estas suponiendo que `dates` es una cadena y en realidad es una lista, ahí tienes un problema de lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí `dates.split("-")[0]` estas suponiendo que `dates` es una cadena y en realidad es una lista (`split()` es un metodo que no existe en un objeto tipo `list`), ahí tienes un problema de lógica, que si me guio por el resto del código, podrías resolverlo con una comprensión de listas para operar sobre `dates`

```
data = {'LOCAL': genres[:8], 
        'GOLES': [d.split("-")[0] for d in dates[:8]] , 
        'VISITANTE': genras[:8],
        'GOLES': [d.split("-")[1] for d in dates[:8]]}
```

Comment: Hola!!!!! Funciona a la perfección!!!!!! Ya sé que debe ser un error bastante absurdo pero siendo novato sin tener ni idea XDDDDDD. 
De verdad. Muchísimas gracias!!!!!! Estoy empezando con python y me queda un camino muuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuy largo por hacer!!! A seguir!!!!